# How do I use node-sass and sass-autoprefixer together?

Tags: javascript, css, npm, sass, package.json

I have code in `package.json`, but I am confused to implement that.

This is my code

```
{
  "name": "nodesass",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies":
    "sass-autoprefixer": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive --use sass-autoprefixer",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Result is autoprefixer not working.

Answer (score 0):

This package is not ran from the CLI. Instead, you need to use it within your .scss files.

First, you need to import the file in the relevant .scss files:

`@import "../path/to/node_modules/sass-autoprefixer/scss/prefixes";`

You can then use the `[sass-autoprefixer][1]` [mixins](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-sass-mixins) in your classes:

```
.your-class {
  // use 'vp-' followed by the CSS property that you want to automatically prefix. Provide the value of the CSS property as the mixin parameter.
  @include vp-flex-flow(row wrap);
}
```

When compiled, the .scss code above will generate the following .css:

```
.your-class {
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

The same logic can be applied to any properties that the package supports. For example:

```
.your-class {
  // Prefixes for `display: flex;`
  @include vp-display(flex);
  // Prefixes for `transform: skewX(50deg);`
  @include vp-transform(skewX(50deg));
}
```